# Copying full components from a folder to another, throwing bad substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

The final.txt looks like:

```sh
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping/camping.design
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

I would like to replace only replace the files which contains `/aura/` in its line to `src/aura/camping`

I have written the below code, but it throws error:

`echo replaceText ${\$CFILE//\$CFILE/"src/aura/"($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))}`

`line 62: ${\$CFILE//\$CFILE/"src/aura/"($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))}: bad substitution`

This `($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")` gives camping
And `$CFILE` gives `src/aura/camping/camping.design`.

But its not replacing `src/aura/camping/camping.design` with `src/aura/camping`

```sh
function contains() {
    local n=$#
    local value=${!n}
    for ((i=1;i < $#;i++)) {
        if [ "${!i}" == "${value}" ]; then
            echo "y"
            return 0
        fi
    }
    echo "n"
    return 1
}

if [ -e final.txt ]
then
        ARRAY=()
        while read CFILE
            do
                    echo Analyzing file `basename $CFILE`
                    case "$CFILE"
                    in
                        *.app) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.cmp) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.css) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.evt) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.js) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.svg) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.auradoc) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *.design) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *) TYPENAME="UNKNOWN";;
                    esac

                    if [ "$TYPENAME" == "AuraDefinitionBundle" ]
                        then
                                if [ $(contains "${ARRAY[@]}" $(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")) != "y" ]
                                then
                                    echo baseFile from new method cFile $CFILE
                                    ARRAY+=($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))
                                    echo replaceText ${\$CFILE//\$CFILE/"src/aura/"($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))}

                                else
                                    continue
                                 fi
                        fi
            done < final.txt
else
echo Change file not found!
fi
```

At last it runs `cat final.txt | xargs -I {} cp --parents {} $1`
which i suppose should copy all the files from the `campaign` folder to another filepath.

**Tried**

```sh
 echo baseFile from new method cFile $CFILE
 FILENAME = "$CFILE"
 ARRAY+=($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))
 replace=$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")
 echo relaceWord $replace
 echo replaceText ${FILENAME//$CFILE/$replace}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `${parameter/pattern/replacement}` expansion takes the name of a parameter as the first element. So `foo=bar; echo "${foo/a/x}"` would output `bxr`. In 
`${\$CFILE//\$CFILE/"src/aura/"($(...))}`, `\$CFILE` is not a valid parameter, so you get an error. If you want to run the replacement on the contents of `CFILE`, you'd use `${CFILE/...}`.

Note that in the "pattern" part, the backslash escapes the dollar sign, so `\$CFILE` would look for the literal string `$CFILE`. Then again, using `${CFILE/$CFILE/...}` would take the contents of `CFILE` as both the text to do the replacement on, and as the text to use as the pattern. It would replace the whole contents of the variable<sup>(*)</sup>. That would be the same as just writing out the replacement part without the parameter at all, so I'm not exactly sure what it is you're doing here.

<sub>(* Unless it's a glob that doesn't match itself, of course.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes, I was able to understand that part, thus I changed it to `${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/$replace}` where `CFILENAME="$CFILE"` and `replace="src/aura/"$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")`. BUt now it gives error as line 66: src/aura/camping: Is a directory

Comment: I am not able to understand what does it matter to bash, if I replace file with folder, it should just work as string replacement. right?